# How To get The name Of Calling activity by any Started Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have Four Activities in my application.

Pressing a button on first three activities Leads To the Fourth Activity. I Used intent For Starting the fourth activity.

In the Fourth Activity. I have A text View Which Changes Its text As Follows: -

if the Activity 4 Was started by Activity 1: The text changes to 0.
if the Activity 4 Was started by Activity 2: The text changes to1.
if the Activity 4 was started by Activity 3: the text Changes to 2.

I Declared an intent like this
For First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("callingActivity",0);
startActivity(intent);
```

For second Activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("callingActivity",1);
   startActivity(intent);
```

For Third Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("callingActivity",2);
startActivity(intent);
```

And at Fourth Activity, to fetch the Data I used intents like this.. :

```
  public int checkCallingActivity() {
            int callingActivity;
            callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("callingActivity", 7);
            return callingActivity;
        }
```

But when i run the Programme and Call the Activity 4 from either activity 1,2 or 3, it doesn't take the intent value.. It takes the Default value which is 7 in this case. What is the logical error in the code and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Can you please post your Main4Activity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for getting activity  name if MainActivity is calling Activity for another Activity

```
String callingActivityName = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("callingActivity", 7)
```

Do this:

```
int callingActivity = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("callingActivity");
```

This should work.

Comment: The app crashed when i replaced the Method.

Comment: callingActivity = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("callingActivity"); makes the app crash?

Comment: Now it worked.. Actually there was some mistake at the other part of The programme and this method worked

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("callingActivity", 7);
```

with:

```
callingActivity = getIntent().getIntExtra("callingActivity", 0);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The app crashed when I replaced my code with above code

Answer (score 0):

In your `Main4Activity's` `onCreate()` method, try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ............
    ...................

    int callingActivity = 0;
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        callingActivity = bundle.getInt("callingActivity");
    }

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(callingActivity));
}
```